# PL/SQL Error on trigger for auto_increment

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to auto_increment the cust_id field in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE A113222813_CUSTOMERS (
CUST_ID  NUMBER(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_FNAME VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_SNAME VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_UNAME  VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
CUST_PASS  VARCHAR2(40)  NOT NULL
)
```

I create the following sequence and trigger to handle this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CUST_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CUST_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON A113222813_CUSTOMERS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
:NEW.CUST_ID := CUST_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

But it keeps throwing the following error:

```
Error(2,30): PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CUST_SEQ.NEXTVAL' not allowed   
in this context
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that you are using 11g?  The error you're getting would make perfect sense if you were using an earlier version of Oracle that didn't support using sequences in direct assignments like this.  But you've tagged the question specifically for 11g...

Comment: This syntax is allowed in Oracle 11 release, so if you work in elder versions of Oracle you should use SELECT CUST_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :NEW.CUST_ID from dual.

Comment: Thats it. My apologies. Its 10g when I was under the impression it was 11g based on the manual I received. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible before 11g. You can use sequence_name.NEXTVAL in regular assignments from 11g not before that, and that by the following:

```
 select CUST_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :NEW.CUST_ID from   dual;
```